# Problem with HashMap values()

Tags: java, collections

I make tile memory game. I want when activity start to init tiles with pictures. I try do this:

```
private void initTiles() {
    // Store name of resources in array
    String[] pictures = new String[] {"tile_circle", "tile_deny", "tile_heart"
                     , "tile_mail", "tile_music", "tile_pin", "tile_splash", "tile_yes"};
    Random rand = new Random();

    int i = 1;

    while(i <= 16) {
        String pic = pictures[rand.nextInt(8)];
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

        list = (LinkedList<String>) tilesMapping.values();

         //Check if this picture is already loaded twice
        if(list.indexOf(pic) == -1) {
            tilesMapping.put(Integer.valueOf(i), pic);
            i++;
        } else if(list.lastIndexOf(pic) == -1) {
            tilesMapping.put(Integer.valueOf(i), pic);
            i++;
        } else if(list.indexOf(pic) == list.lastIndexOf(pic)) {
            tilesMapping.put(Integer.valueOf(i), pic);
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

But when I start game I receive  force close.  But when comment this row `list = (LinkedList<String>) tilesMapping.values();` The game starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`values()` returns a `Collection`, it does not need to be a `LinkedList`, so perhaps a `ClassCastException` happens. You can obtain a linked list by using a copy-constructor:

```
List list = new LinkedList(map.values()); // or ArrayList`
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the code

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list = (LinkedList<String>) tilesMapping.values();
```

is inside your foreach loop doesn't look right me. I guess it should be above to loop.

Also, you probably didn't mean to create a `new LinkedList()` and then immediately throw it away, by setting the only reference to that object to the result of `tilesMapping.values()`... which (presumably) contains one you prepared earlier, yes?

Which brings us to the real problem: What is `tilesMapping.values()`, and specifically what type does it return? You can't just make something that is NOT really a `LinkedList` into a linked-list of strings just by type casting it. You can fool the compiler, but it still won't work at runtime.

Cheers. Keith.